# recoger los datos de un index.htm.erb scaffold en ruby y llevarlos a otro index.html scaffold a traves de un link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Este es el código de `index.html.erb` de mi *scaffold* `contactos`:

```
<h1>Contactos</h1>
<br>

<table class= "table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellidos</th>
      <th>Empresa</th>
 <th>ID</th>

      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @contactos.each do |contacto| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= contacto.nombre %></td>
        <td><%= contacto.apellidos %></td>
        <td><%= contacto.empresa %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', contacto %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contacto_path(contacto) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', contacto, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td> 
        <td><%= link_to 'Negociacions', new_negociacion_path(contacto.nombre),  data: { confirm: 'Quiere añadir una negociacion para el contacto: '+(contacto.empresa)+'?'}%></td>
```

Tiene varios links: `show`, `edit`, `destroy` y `negociacion`. Cuando pincho en `negociacion` me lleva a "nueva negociación", me gustaría que me cogiera los datos del contacto y me los lleve directamente a negociación. Todo ello porque lo que quiero es crear una nueva negociación con los datos de un contacto, y como seria muy costoso recordar el nombre, apellidos y empresa, creo que es mejor si los recogiera y los mandara directamente.

Con `new_negociacion_path(contacto.nombre)` que tiene el link de negociación, lo que consigo es que efectivamente me coja el nombre del contacto y me lo muestra cuando se abre `new negociacion`, y lo veo en el browser así:

http://localhost:3000/negociacions/new.Lucas

¿Cómo podría que en este caso el nombre de `Lucas` (también apellidos y empresa) me los ponga directamente en los campos de `new negociacion`: nombre, apellidos, empresa?

Este es el código del controlador contactos:

```
class ContactosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_contacto, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  layout "bienvenida" 

 # GET /contactos
  # GET /contactos.json
  def index
    @contactos = Contacto.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page:10)
  end

  # GET /contactos/1
  # GET /contactos/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /contactos/new
  def new
    @contacto = Contacto.new
  end

  # GET /contactos/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /contactos
  # POST /contactos.json
  def create
    @contacto = Contacto.new(contacto_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contacto.save
        format.html { redirect_to @contacto, notice: 'Contacto was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contacto }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @contacto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /contactos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /contactos/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contacto.update(contacto_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @contacto, notice: 'Contacto was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @contacto }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @contacto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /contactos/1
  # DELETE /contactos/1.json
  def destroy
    @contacto.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to contactos_url, notice: 'Contacto was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_contacto
      @contacto = Contacto.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def contacto_params
      params.require(:contacto).permit(:nombre, :apellidos, :edad, :empresa, :domicilio, :localidad, :provincia, :pais, :telefono, :movil, :email, :foto, :descripcion, :notas, :cargo, :sitioweb, :agente_id)
    end
end
```

y el modelo de contactos:

```
class Contacto < ApplicationRecord
    mount_uploader :foto, FotoUploader
    validates :nombre, presence: true
    has_many :negociacions
    has_many :agente_comercials
    has_many :tareas
    has_many :sales
    has_one :cliente
end
```

Comment: como tienes la ruta de negotiation path ? puesto que si quieres que te cargue datos deberías  de tenerla asi `ruta/:id` y en el controlador usando esa id puedes generar un `Modelo.find(params[:id])` para obtener todo lo que quieras de ese registro.

Comment: ¿puedes explayarte un poco más en lo que quieres? ¿a que datos te refieres? ¿los datos de un formulario? ¿los datos que cargas en el action del index?. Pon el código relevante ¿cual es la otra vista?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [recoger los datos de un index.html.erb scaffold en ruby y llevarlos a otro index.html scaffold a traves un link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171143/recoger-los-datos-de-un-index-html-erb-scaffold-en-ruby-y-llevarlos-a-otro-index)

Comment: Hola Mariovcz, creo que me has entendido, pero podrias ser porfavor un poco mas explicito?

Comment: Hola Alter Lagos,te comento. En contactos index tengo una lista de contactos con nombre,apellidos y otros campos y seguidamente tengo el show, edit, destroy y negociacion.Cuando pincho al link de negociacion, quiero que los datos del usuario (nombre y apellidos) me sean recogidos en negociacion ,directamente en new negociacion, para asi no tenerlos que teclear. Eso es lo que quiero hacer en definitiva, porque tengo una relacion de que un contacto puede tener muchas negociaciones.A traves del link quiero que me recoga  los datos del contacto para que se me guarden en una nueva negociacion.

Comment: Si Mariovcz esta es la ruta de negociacion: <td><%= link_to 'Negociacions', new_negociacion_path(contacto.nombre),  data: { confirm: 'Quiere añadir una negociacion para el contacto: '+(contacto.empresa)+'?'}%></td>  y asi como la tengo, cuando pincho a negociacion, se me abre una nueva negociacion, claro, pero no me guarda el nombre en el campo nombre de negociacion, sin embargo si que me lo muestra en el browser asi: http://localhost:3000/negociacions/new.Lucas y como ves el nombre de "Lucas" quiero que lo meta directamente al campo nombre de new negociacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer (desde el punto de vista *REST*) es generar una ruta como la que [recomienda mariovzc](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171310/recoger-los-datos-de-un-index-htm-erb-scaffold-en-ruby-y-llevarlos-a-otro-index#comment321504_171310); esto puedes lograrlo anidando rutas en tu archivo *routes.rb*:

```
# config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :contactos do
      resources :negociaciones
  end
end
```

Lo anterior te generará, entre otras, la siguiente ruta:

```
new_contacto_negociacione GET    /contactos/:contacto_id/negociaciones/new(.:format)               negociaciones#new
```

Luego, en tu vista, utiliza la ruta de esta forma:

```
<!-- app/views/contactos/index.html.erb  -->

<% @contactos.each do |contacto| %>
  <!-- otros datos de contacto -->
  <%= link_to 'Negociacion', new_contacto_negociacione_path(contacto),  data: { confirm: 'Quiere añadir una negociacion para el contacto: '+(contacto.empresa)+'?'}%>
<% end %>
```

Y, finalmente, en tu controlador:

```
class NegociacionesController < ApplicationController
  # otras acciones

  def new
    @negociacion = Negociacion.new(contacto_id: params[:contacto_id])
  end
end
```

Si creas la `negocacion` directamente (i.e, sin `contacto_id`) será equivalente a únicamente escribir `Negociacion.new`; pero si tienes `contacto_id`, entonces este será asignado a `negocacion`.

De esta forma podrás utilizar  `@negociacion.contacto` en la vista *new.html.erb* para mostrar los datos del contacto; por ejemplo:

```
<!-- app/views/negociaciones/new.html.erb -->

<%= @negociacion.contacto.nombre %>
<%= @negociacion.contacto.empresa %>
```

Comment: Hola Gerry, tras muchos intentos y comprobaciones de código, al final ha salido siguiendo tus indicaciones. Gracias! ahora desde contactos, puedo hacer una negociacion, y me coje los datos de contactos y los guarda como una nueva negociación. Estupendo! lo único, es que ahora cuando quiero hacer una negociación directamente desde negociaciones, me da un error: contacto=Contacto.find(params[:contacto_id]) y dice que Couldn´t find Contacto with "id"= ... voy a ver si consigo ahora resolver por qué... pero en realidad es por el codigo añadido en el controlador...

Comment: @user87071 Para que funcione en ambos casos, únicamente necesitas cambiar la forma en que construyes el objeto `negociacion` para que utilizes `new` en lugar de `build`. He actualizado la respuesta para que refleje este cambio; con este ajuste ya te debe funcionar sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

disculpa por la tardanza en contestar. Más o menos te pillo por donde vas y lo que sugieres. Gracias.Te comento siguiendo los pasos que indicas: en <% @contactos.each do |contacto| %>, me sale una linea en horizontal con la palabra Negociacion tantas veces como contactos tengo. Sin embargo correcto es en vertical, al lado de cada contacto. Alguna sugerencia para ordenarlos? 
Y en Negociacionescontroller no sé porqué me da un error:  @negociacion = contacto.negociaciones.build , lo he estado repasando y modificando, pero no deja de salir, creo debido al build. Hay posibilidad de mandarte tal vez el codigo? gracias.

Comment: Hola Guerry, muchísimas gracias. Después de darle varias vueltas, no puedo hacerlo, pero no porque no funcione tu solución, sino porque solamente tengon un formulario en negociaciones: _form.html.erb y ahi tengo los campos de los datos que me coje directamente desde contactos. Estos campos se muestran en negociaciones pero no los puedo editar: nombrea, apellidos, etc.. entonces al hacer click en nueva negociacion, claro, me pide los campos que no puedo editar porque previamente me los ha cogido de contactos. Por eso me da error. El problema es como lo tengo yo estructurado. Gracias igualmente!